# Correctly configure IP network when using Python socket library

Tags: python, sockets, ip

I have Python code like the following that makes a TCP connection over Wifi to a Linux microcomputer from my personal laptop. This works when I connected to the Wifi network of the microcomputer from my personal laptop. However, if I'm also connected to another network over ethernet, this does not work.

```
import socket

PORT = 65432
HOST = "192.168.6.2"

socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) # socket creation
socket.connect((HOST, PORT)) # socket connection
```

To address this problem of being connected to Ethernet: when connecting via ssh, I use the following: `ssh -B en0 username@192.168.1.1`. Please see [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/451245/ssh-from-mac-over-wifi-while-also-connected-to-ethernet/451266#451266) for details on the network.

I basically want to to tell the Python socket library to include the `-B en0` option, but am not sure how to do this.